# How to highlight the selected feature in open layers 3

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, openlayers

Right now i am using this code to zoom to the feature selected by drop down list from geojson database. now i want to highlight my selected feature.

```
function Zoomto(filter, SearchResultsLayer) {
var schoolname = $('#ddldistrict').val();
//// alert(districtname);
var filter = "schoolname='" + schoolname + "'";
$.ajax({
    url: owsURL,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
    data: {
        typeName: layerName,
        outputFormat: "text/javascript",
        service: "WFS",
        version: "1.1.0",
        request: "GetFeature",
        CQL_FILTER: filter

    },
    success: function (response) {

        var SearchResultsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        });

        SearchResultsLayer.setSource(null);

        var searchresultssource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(response, {
                featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
            })
        });

        SearchResultsLayer.setSource(searchresultssource);
        map.getView().fit(SearchResultsLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());

    }
    });
}
```

Please anyone can help me out with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight a feature, one way is to create a stroke-style with an other color like this

```js
var style= new ol.style.Style({
             stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                 color: 'rgbColor',
                 width: 2,
             }),
             fill : new ol.style.Fill({
                 color: 'rbgbColor',
             })
         });
feature.setStyle(newStyles);
map.render();
```